# call a program from local terminal while in an ssh session

Tags: ssh, terminal, scp, tramp

Is there some way to call on a local program while using an ssh connection to a remote host? I'd like to have access to the environment on both sessions, so opening another terminal isn't ideal.

**Edit:** specifically the uses would center around [scp](/questions/tagged/scp) or local programs that use it (i.e. the emacs extension [tramp](/questions/tagged/tramp)). The two things I had in mind:

- to be able to type `download x.png` on a remote machine and have the file pulled to my computer.
- something like `emacs-local file.py` that would open emacs on my local computer and use tramp to edit `file.py`.

Comment: You can suspend the `ssh` command in the current terminal (`~` followed by Control+Z), but then you can't get at the `ssh` session until you `fg` it.  What problem are you trying to solve, exactly?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve? The environment isn't shared between local and remote machines, so you can't set an env var in the remote session and then access it in the local session, for example. There's likely a good command/script to do what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: @geekosaur and there are a few uses: open scp locally using `pwd` remotely to set the file to download; open a local text editor which can open the remote file; download and open some file...